# WPF CheckBox IsChecked toggled on different events

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, checkbox

Does anyone know the rationale behind the WPF CheckBox behaviour where it (appears) to display `IsChecked` true on `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and false on `MouseLeftButtonUp` event?

The reason I ask is that I'm implementing a CheckBox in an existing grid where the text is on the left instead of the right of the CheckBox. The easiest way was to add a TextBlock and some code-behind, but if I want to be consistent it means adding both events and checking state on each one.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is CheckBox having text to its left, why not simply modify its template:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFCheckboxTextOnLeft.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/85673c27-01e6-4f8e-96a5-1847bb44abc4

Comment: The checkboxes are on a grid with other controls with their own text blocks, such as combo box and text box. I want the text of the checkbox to be left aligned with the the other text block labels (which is automatically sized, important for i18ln), and the checkbox itself to be correctly aligned with the other data entry controls. I already read the code project article and I don't think it will solve my particular problem in a nice way. My question is really about trying to find the reason why the checkbox behaviour uses different events based on the IsChecked state.